# Question about proof of irrationality of $\pi^2$

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

[image]

It says that $F''(x)+\pi^2 F(x)=b^n\pi^{2n+2}f(x)$

I don't understand.
\begin{align}
\pi^2F(x)=b^n(\pi^{2n+2}f(x) - \pi^{2n}f^{(2)}(x)-\cdots+(-1)^n\pi^2f^{(2n)}(x)) 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
 F''(x) =b^n(\pi^{2n}f^{(2)}(x) - \pi^{2n-2}f^{(4)}(x)-\cdots+(-1)^nf^{(2n)}(x))
\end{align}

When adding both equations some terms cancel each other, but what happened to $(-1)^n\pi^2f^{(2n)}(x)?$

Edit: $$f(x)=\frac{x^n(1-x)^n}{n!} $$

Comment: Isn't it just a different $n$ between the two equations, so you can't equate the two terms with each other?

Comment: What is $f(x)$?  is it a polynomial?

Comment: Ok...so $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2n$.  That explains why there are no derivatives higher than $2n$.  But then the problem seems to be in your computation of $F''(x)$.  $F(x)$ has a term that looks like $\pi^2f^{2n-2}$ so when you differentiate it twice you get $\pi^2 f^{2n}$ as desired.

Comment: @lulu oh, I see now... thanks